# Map displayed in this airplane cabin

Tags: air-travel, airlines, identify-this

Would anyone know where the map with both the rendering and the meta-data of the photo below can be found online?

[image: Image credits: https://liveandletsfly.boardingarea.com/2018/08/31/middle-east-airlines-a320-business-class-review/]
*Image credits: https://liveandletsfly.boardingarea.com/2018/08/31/middle-east-airlines-a320-business-class-review/*

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you talking just about the satellite image, or about the map overlay on top of it (cities, borders, etc.)?

Comment: @TooTea: they are not satellite images. It is rendering.

Comment: The answer to the generic question is "it depends", as there are many different IFEs in use onboard, which have different software features, and most certainly different sources for their maps. So I guess your question is rather "what is the source of the maps used on the specific IFE pictured"?

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments. I have improved the question accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

A typical source of such images are  databases from NASA : for instance the seasonal  [*"Blue Marble"*](https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view_cat.php?categoryID=1484)  cloudless earth  and the "Black Marble" night lights images. That image dataset is as far as I know free of copyright.

The inflight system vendor will probably have used some customization and added additional layers  specific to the capabilities of their system and the requirements of the airline.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer HBruijn! Would you know if the inflight customization itself could be found somewhere?